# ElasticSearch (Opensearch) update documents performance issues

Tags: java, elasticsearch, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I have a question about elasticsearch (opensearch) on AWS.

examples with spring boot data usage:

```
package com.ecommerce.inventory.core.model.index;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Version;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Field;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.FieldType;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;

@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(indexName = "product_inventory_index_v1")
public class ProductInventoryIndex {

    @Id
    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String productId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<InventoryItem> inventoryItems;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String productStatus;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private Instant restockDate;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private Instant soldOutDate;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private Instant createDate;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private Instant updateDate;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private List<ProductCategory> categories;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long productVersion;

    @Version
    @Field(type = FieldType.Long)
    private Long indexVersion;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String productName;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
    private SupplierInfo supplierInfo;

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class SupplierInfo {

        @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
        private String id;

        @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
        private String name;
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class InventoryItem {

        @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
        private String warehouseId;

        @Field(type = FieldType.Integer)
        private Integer stockLevel;
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class ProductCategory {

        @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
        private String categoryId;
    }
}
```

and have simple logic i.e.

```
package com.ecommerce.inventory.core.service;

import com.ecommerce.inventory.core.model.index.ProductInventoryIndex;
import com.ecommerce.inventory.core.repository.InventoryRepository;
import com.ecommerce.inventory.core.mapper.InventoryMapper;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InventoryService {

    private final InventoryRepository inventoryRepository;
    private final InventoryMapper inventoryMapper;

    public ProductInventoryIndex upsert(ProductInventoryIndex request) {
        ProductInventoryIndex indexToUpsert = inventoryRepository.findById(request.getId())
            .map(existingIndex -> inventoryMapper.update(existingIndex, request))
            .orElseGet(() -> inventoryMapper.create(request)); 

        return inventoryRepository.save(indexToUpsert);
    }
}
```

At first I did migration data from mongoDB to elastic just via simple find from mongo -> save in elastic.
And started to consume data from kafka.
It was like 2 mil events in the topic (5 partitions), and at 1st hour 5 consumers (they using the service saving logic) did like 300k events and saved it. But each hour the amount of saved/updated documents started dropping, and at 5th hour it was like 50k per hour, and when processed like 600k out of 2 mil from kafka, it is started to process like 1k per 5 minutes, maybe slowly (remember it is 5 consumer replicas). After reprocessed like 900k messages from kafka it is almost stopped updating documents in elastic (like 3 documents per second). Logic in consumer the same:
as in service

```
public ProductInventoryIndex upsert(ProductInventoryEvent event) {
        ProductInventoryIndex indexToUpsert = inventoryRepository.findById(event.getId())
            .map(existingIndex -> inventoryMapper.update(existingIndex, event)) 
            .orElseGet(() -> inventoryMapper.create(request)); 

        return inventoryRepository.save(indexToUpsert);
    }
```

It was on instance **t3.medium.search**, and I created a new instance **m6g.xlarge.search** but the problem is the same, event when hardware characteristics almost x4.
I read that elasticsearch deleting previous version of a document and creating a new one, but it should be protected with the amount of load, doesn't it?
I expected to update document via 3 consumers, loading 700-800k messages per day overall for all consumers.
[image: key performance metrics]
very first spike is when I did script migrate data from mongo to elastic, but I did batch. dont look at the last spike, i did some other tests, just ignore the latest spike.
also[image: metrics for node loading, also ignore the latest spike, some other tests not related what I posted in the question]

Why this happened with elasticsearch? Is it not possible to use it as mongoDB and store-update a data? I needed it to be able to do more search filters, because it is not useful to create all indexes in mongoDB and elastic gives it from the box. In my case it should be like 9-10 mil documents at all, with daily updates 700-800k events overall from kafka topics.